# Can an Ansible inventory file have hosts belonging to different OS?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

Can an Ansible inventory file have hosts belonging to different OS?

Let us say, we want to deploy a Java Web application on multiple machines (a set of machines) where each machine has a different OS than the rest of the machines. Can we write a single play-book which can set-up the Java Web application on each of these machines?

Will the approach be as follows?
1. In the playbook, check for the OS type (if-conditions), and then in each if block, do the installation steps (application set-up steps) accordingly. If there are any common installation steps then have those tasks outside the OS type check condition (if condition).

Comment: Of course, this is absolutely legal. You may set host identifiers in your inventory to distinguish operation systems, or use builtin gathered fact `ansible_os_family`

Comment: Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can have in your inventory mixed OS instances.
You can handle the deployment in your playbook by adding a "when" condition per task e.g:

```
- name: "Install the Python bindings for SELinux, for Ansible."
  yum: name=libselinux-python state=present
  when: ansible_os_family == "RedHat"
```

Or in your tasks folder of your role create different file per OS and in the main fiel you can use something like this:

```
- include: Debian.yml
  when: ansible_os_family == "Debian"

- include: RedHat.yml
  when: ansible_os_family == "RedHat"

- include: Windows.yml
  when: ansible_os_family == "Windows"
```